# How to set the timestamp format when reading CSV in Spark +2.4

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a Databricks 5.3 cluster on Azure which runs Apache Spark 2.4.0 and Scala 2.11.

I'm trying to parse a CSV file with a custom timestamp format but I don't know which datetime pattern format Spark uses.

My CSV looks like this:

```
Timestamp, Name, Value
02/07/2019 14:51:32.869-08:00, BatteryA, 0.25
02/07/2019 14:55:45.343-08:00, BatteryB, 0.50
02/07/2019 14:58:25.845-08:00, BatteryC, 0.34
```

I'm executing the following to read it:

```
%scala

val csvDataFrame = sqlContext.read.format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("mode","DROPMALFORMED")
  .option("timestampFormat", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ")
  .load("path/to/file.csv")

csvDataFrame.printSchema()
```

But no matter what timestamp pattern I use, the first column is always inferred as string.

```
csvDataFrame:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
  Timestamp:string
  Name:string
  Value:double
```

I'm not a Java/Scala developer and I'm new to Spark/Databricks. I can't find anywhere which datetime formatter does Spark use to parse the values.

Patterns I tried:

```
MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ
MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX
```

Comment: I think the format should be "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX". Has that been tried? Also is the date MM/dd and not dd/MM - the example data could be either way.

Comment: Maybe the time format? MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX.  Edit: same that @simon_dmorias said

Comment: Nope, same thing.

Comment: Databricks docs talks about 'dateFormat' option instead ' timestampFormat' 
 https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/read-csv.html. Test it

Comment: @gasparms Wow, I miss that completely. But unfortunately, I'm still getting the timestamp as string... I honestly thought that was it, but no.

Comment: dateFormat doesn't do anything. Correct option is timestampFormat, as in Spark. My problem was caused by a malformed line in my CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the Databricks docs mention a `dateFormat` option when reading/writing CSV files, but it doesn't do anything.
The correct option is the same Spark uses, called `timestampFormat`.

My problem was caused by a malformed line in my file. Even with DROPMALFORMED, that line was causing the timestamp to be interpreted as string.